# Setting up a payment database (payment listener) with PayPal

Tags: javascript, php, paypal

I just need people to pay me on my site and I need to have statistics with the payments. I was searching for such a long time but I just couldn't find a proper code to do it.

Is there a way to just log every payment as it is made and store it, applying statistics to it later when i want to?

Thanks very much, last time i asked i was pretty much ignored

Comment: You'll probably get ignored again, people will only respond if they can clearly see you have tried, what kind of setup do you currently have?

Comment: As @Zanderwar said, questions which show little to no effort in researching or including the code / things they've tried in order to get the issue solved, often get ignored due to the simple fact that we aren't a free coding service, nor clairvoyant so that we automatically know what it is you want. - If you want your question to get a better reception, do as much as you can to clarify your issue, what you have tried in order to solve it, and provide as much information **RELEVANT** to the issue as you can (Don't just dump a lot of code.) - Look at the help section to get a better idea :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is Paypal Instant Payment Notification (IPN):

See: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/

PHP Example: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/

Answer (score 0):

You can enable IPN feature in PayPal account, then insert each payment into database.

Refer to 
http://www.rahulsingla.com/blog/2011/11/drupal-handling-paypal-ipn-callbacks-and-saving-data-to-the-database

https://canvascode.wordpress.com/2014/07/22/how-to-set-up-paypal-integration-with-php-mysql/

Comment: Paypal provides their own up to date examples, I wouldn't trust anything from 2011 regarding Paypal IPN